# Can i convert setTimeout method to observable.timer?

Tags: angular, timer, observable

Hear i am iterating array and i want to run this loop after every 2 sec.

```
 let Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  
      for (i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
          setTimeout((item)=>{
           //business logic
          console.log("item", item);
          }, 2000 * i, Array[i]);
    }
```

How can i convert this code in observable.timer method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work:

```js
    let Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
rxjs.interval(2000)
.pipe(
    rxjs.operators.take(Array.length),
    rxjs.operators.map(i => Array[i])
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

It automatically ends after `Array.length` items (`take`) and yields the items in subscribe (`map`) instead of their index.

RxJS v5 Version:

```js
    let Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
Rx.Observable.interval(2000)
.take(Array.length)
.map(i => Array[i])
.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.12/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're not incrementing interval by the multiple of index.

Comment: I don't need to. OP's intervals all start at the same time so it yields a value every two seconds. Mine does the same.

Comment: @tkausl thanks for quick reply. 
I tried second one,  but as per scenario value should be console after every 2 sec. which is not triggering . please help to complete the logic thanks.

Comment: @NeerajShrimali you're right, I was misunderstanding the `debounce` operator. First one works though.

Comment: @tkausl This map will work only rxjs 6+ version, any idea about rxjs 5 version, how can i achieve this.

Comment: @NeerajShrimali Added a version which works for me in v5.5.12

Answer (score 1):

well done, there should be a es6 version with rxjs 6.x :

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
interval(2000)
  .pipe(take(array.length))
  .pipe(map(i => array[i]))
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log(val)
  );
```